# i need help TypeError: Fishing_Location() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self' pls

Tags: python

```py
#imports
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller
import cv2 as cv
import time
import mss
import pyaudio
import math
import struct
import numpy as np
import time
import pyautogui
from sshkeyboard import listen_keyboard, stop_listening

mouse = Controller()

#variables
Threshold = 30
SHORT_NORMALIZE = (1.0/32768.0)
chunk = 1024
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 16000
swidth = 2
bait=0
bait_total=0
FishingSpots = []
fishing_location1=[]
fishing_location2=[]
fishing_location3=[]

def press(key):
    if key == "1":
        FishingSpots.append(mouse.position)
        time.sleep(1)
        print(FishingSpots)        
    
    if len(FishingSpots)>=3:
        fishing_location1, fishing_location2,fishing_location3 = [FishingSpots[i] for i in (0, 1, 2)]
        print('location taken')
        stop_listening()

listen_keyboard(on_press=press)

#mouse
def mouse_down():
    mouse.press(Button.left)
def mouse_up():
    mouse.release(Button.left) 


class Fishing:
    @staticmethod

    def Fishing_Location(self):
        while 1:
            pos=0
            if pos==0:
                mouse.position = (fishing_location1)
                mouse_down()
                time.sleep(1)
                mouse_up()
                pos=pos+1
                break
            if pos==1:
                mouse.position = (fishing_location2)
                mouse_down()
                time.sleep(1)
                mouse_up()
                pos=pos+1
                break
            if pos==3:
                mouse.position = (fishing_location3)
                mouse_down()
                time.sleep(1)
                mouse_up()
                break
      
    def rms(frame):
        count = len(frame) / swidth
        format = "%dh" % (count)
        shorts = struct.unpack(format, frame)

        sum_squares = 0.0
        for sample in shorts:
            n = sample * SHORT_NORMALIZE
            sum_squares += n * n
        rms = math.pow(sum_squares / count, 0.5)

        return rms * 1000

    def __init__(self):
        self.p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
        self.stream = self.p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16,
                                  channels=CHANNELS,
                                  rate=RATE,
                                  input=True,
                                  output=True,
                                  frames_per_buffer=chunk)
  
    def listen(self):
        while True:
            input = self.stream.read(chunk)
            rms_val = self.rms(input)
            print(rms_val)
            if rms_val > Threshold:
                mouse_down()
                time.sleep(0.1)
                mouse_up()
                break

    def minigame():
        mouse_down()
        while 1:
        #minigame
            needle_img = cv.imread('bob.png', cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE) 
            method = cv.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED
            #screenshot full screen
            with mss.mss() as sct:
                 region = {'top': 380, 'left': 420, 'width': 172, 'height': 25}
                 fullscreen = sct.grab(region)    
            fullscreen=np.array(fullscreen)
            fullscreen = cv.cvtColor(fullscreen, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)  
            resultfull = cv.matchTemplate(fullscreen, needle_img, method)
            min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv.minMaxLoc(resultfull)
        
            #minigame function    
            threshold = 0.7
            if max_loc >= (137,6) and max_val>=0.7:
               mouse_up()
            elif max_val<= threshold:
                time.sleep(2)
                break
            else:
                mouse_down()
fish=Fishing()
max_time = 300
start_time = time.time()
while (time.time() - start_time) < max_time:
    print('Fishing Started 1')
    fish.Fishing_Location()
    print('fish threw 2')
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print('starting audio detection')
    fish.listen()
    ('fish located')
    fish.minigame()
    bait=bait+1
    bait_total=bait_total+1
    if bait >= 10:
        pyautogui.keyDown('1')
        time.sleep(1)
        pyautogui.keyUp('1')
        print('bait used')
        bait=bait-10
    if bait_total>=100: 
        pyautogui.keyDown('i')
        time.sleep(0.5)
        pyautogui.rightClick()# need to add position
        time.sleep(0.5)
        pyautogui.keyUp('i')
        bait_total=bait_total-100   
                  
else:
    time.sleep(5)
    print('food used')
    pyautogui.keyDown('2')
    time.sleep(1)
    pyautogui.keyUp('2')
```

ok so i need spme help i need to paste here to type cus i cant paste so help me i am getting this error TypeError: Fishing_Location() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self' so pls help me i need more words lol this is sad i dont know i will just write yoda baby yoda dfasdfadsfasdfasdfadsfadasdasdada

Answer (score 0):

In the provided code `Fishing_Location` is a static method. Static methods in Python don't use self as the first argument. You need to either remove the `@staticmethod` decorator or remove the self argument from the method, i.e. `def Fishing_Location()`.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `fish.Fishing_Location()` on `while` loop you're not providing any value. However, `Fishing_Location` is an static method with a `self` var declared and not used. Thus, when you call `Fishing_Location` method it raises a `TypeError` since you're not providing any value.

So basically all you need to do is remove `self` from `Fishing_Location` method.